# Trouble getting A4 output from custom class

Tags: document-classes, paper-size, class-options

I am trying to get an A4 output from a document with a custom class (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article). I tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,11pt]{SelfArx}
```

in the document file but unfortunately I don't get an A4 PDF. I also tried to put `[a4paper]` in the class document, but also no luck there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class loads the `geometry` package with the following options:

```
\RequirePackage[
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2.25cm,
    bottom=2.25cm,
    headheight=11pt,
    letterpaper,
]{geometry}
```

Notice that the size of the paper is letter. You need to change that. Simply pass a new argument to geometry to set the paper to A4 using

```
\geometry{a4paper}
```

Anywhere in your preamble. This would change the size to A4.

Mind, though, that the margins will remain those set in the class. Also, if you received this class from a journal or a conference, they would expect you not to change the dimensions of the paper.

Comment: oh I skimmed the class but missed this I deleted my answer (+1)